# My switch/case is working but giving a console error "Cannot read property 'name' of null"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here's the working codepen http://codepen.io/TylerL-uxai/pen/ozNgVb

When I do the third drop down and choose elephant, console.log(brand.name) says elephant. It will even do the rest of the switch statement.

But there's a console error for some reason.

```
$scope.changedValue3 = function (brand) {
 console.log(brand.name); // this isn't null! it returns elephant to console.
 switch (brand.name){ // cannot read property name of null
   case "elephant":
     console.log("worked"); // says "worked" when the code is run
     break;
 }
}
```

Comment: the error is NOT where you say it is - "worked" is logged to the console just before the error - therefore the `cannot read property name of null` error can't be where you claim it is

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue has to do with a collision over the `ng-model` set on the `select` element. Because `$scope.logos` is where the data is stored, you'll need something different for `ng-model`. This works out on my end:

```
<select ng-model="logo" ng-options="item as item.brand for item in logos" ng-change="changedValue3(logo)" class="form-control">
```

Note that `ng-model` has been changed as well as the function in `ng-change` in order to pass the model to the function.

[Here](http://codepen.io/EranSch/pen/RGwPpL) is my fork if you want to check it out in the flesh.